# Cannot start apache automatically with docker

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I made a simple custom docker setup for php development. So far everything works as expected. The only thing that I cannot figure out is why apache2 does not start automatically.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql php-cli php-curl php-xml php-intl php-mbstring git vim composer curl

COPY . /var/www/example
COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf

RUN a2ensite example
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example/logs
RUN service apache2 restart
```

And here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myexampleapp
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    tty: true
```

And here is the output docker-compose up command:

```
me@mydell:~/workspace/mydockercompose$ docker-compose up -d --build
Creating network "mydockercompose_default" with the default driver
Building app
Step 1/7 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> f975c5035748
Step 2/7 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql php-cli php-curl php-xml php-intl php-mbstring git vim composer curl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 148c3a9d928a
Step 3/7 : COPY . /var/www/example
 ---> 1fbc1dbacf1e
Step 4/7 : COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf
 ---> 9c08947b09e9
Step 5/7 : RUN a2ensite example
 ---> Running in 1ef64defe747
Enabling site example.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
Removing intermediate container 1ef64defe747
 ---> ca1c8e7e80fc
Step 6/7 : RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example/logs
 ---> Running in 57b0214be7a0
Removing intermediate container 57b0214be7a0
 ---> b3b270a36bf4
Step 7/7 : RUN service apache2 restart
 ---> Running in 09d2b1d3bd91
 * Restarting Apache httpd web server apache2
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
   ...done.
Removing intermediate container 09d2b1d3bd91
 ---> 19fa9a90f9de
Successfully built 19fa9a90f9de
Successfully tagged myexampleapp:latest
Creating mydockercompose_app_1
```

It shows clearly that apache was restarted successfully. However it actually does not:

```
me@mydell:~/workspace/mydockercompose$ docker exec -i -t 20add8ad9895 service apache2 status
 * apache2 is not running
```

I am new to docker, so all suggestions (even if  they are not answering this specific question) to improve what I am doing so far are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Docker services have to be running in the foreground. In your Dockerfile, `RUN service apache2 restart` will start apache as background process. Hence the container will exit.

To run apache in the foreground, add the following to the Dockerfile.

`CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql php-cli php-curl php-xml php-intl php-mbstring git vim composer curl

COPY . /var/www/example
COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf

RUN a2ensite example
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example/logs
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: here is the command that worked for me: CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

Comment: The "/usr/sbin/apachectl" WORKS,   but "apachectl" does NOT.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is probably correct that mentioned that you can start it with:

```
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

With docker it is sometimes a good idea to use the absolute path to a binary. So for example maybe do this instead:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
```

I had a look a bit on google to see what other people are doing. I found this example of a dockerfile where the guy mentions a script start.sh:
From here: https://github.com/jacksoncage/apache-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 80
ADD start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod 0755 /start.sh
CMD ["bash", "start.sh"]
```

Here is the start.sh script: https://github.com/jacksoncage/apache-docker/blob/master/start.sh

Which simply just does:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start apache
/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
```

Unrelated tip:
Your dockerfile you need to pin the version for Ubuntu.
See: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-18-please-pin-your-docker-image-versions

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I was able to make it run using the start script but with some tweaking ...

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks for feeback :)

Answer (score 0):

If it help you or anybody, i was preparing working example with complete docker-composer:
https://github.com/marekz/docker-composer-example

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
EXPOSE 80
ENV TZ=Europe/Warsaw

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-gd php7.2-intl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml php7.2-xsl php7.2-bcmath php7.2-zip php-apcu npm lynx
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client composer screen tmux vim nano iputils-ping


ENTRYPOINT service apache2 restart && bash
```

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing the statements, I found a solution to my error

File: Dockerfile

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update -qq >/dev/null && apt-get install -y -qq procps telnet apache2 php7.3 -qq >/dev/null
RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app
RUN mkdir /data && chown -R app /data && chmod 777 /data
COPY php.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.3.conf
RUN a2enmod userdir && a2enmod php7.3
```

Error:

```
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
```

Solutions:

```
FROM debian -> FROM debian:10
```

The reason was some conflict between the debian system and the php version. The latest version of debian has a newer version of PHP (PHP 7.4 at that time).